# if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || !isset($_COOKIE['admin'])):

Tags: php, cookie

Вообщем я столкнулся с такой проблемой: Мне надо сделать проверку сохранена ли cookie ['user'] или ['admin']. Если нет, то выводить в header болк с кнопкой входа/регистрации, а если есть, то проверить isset($_COOKIE['admin']). Если да, то вывести блок с кнопками добавить товар и выход, если isset($_COOKIE['admin']) неверно, то просто кнопку выхода.
Весь код рабочий, если по одиночке делать проверку(Например:if(!isset($_COOKIE['admin'])):), то выведет кнопки добавить товар и выход, а если (if(!isset($_COOKIE['user'])):), то только кнопку выхода.
Вот основной код:

```
<?php 
  if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || !isset($_COOKIE['admin'])):
     ***Кусок html разметки***
?>
<?php else: ?>
     <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['admin'])): ?>
         ***Кусок html разметки***
     <?php endif; ?>
     ***Кусок html разметки***
<?php endif; ?>
```

У меня не получается всё это объединить, чтобы была одновременная проверка двух cookie.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || !isset($_COOKIE['admin'])):
Не рабочий код(но в моём уме он должен работать))
```

Может кто-то знает как эту проблему решить?

```
<?php                      
   if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || !isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) {                         
      echo('                             
         HTML Code                         
      ');                     
   } else {                         
      if(isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) {                             
         echo('                                 
           HTML Code                             
         ');                         
   };                         
   echo('                             
      HTML Code                         
   ');                     
   };                 
?>
```

Код выше не решает проблему и пробный вариант.
Это код создания куки при авторизации:

```
<!-- В auth.php (авторизация) -->
    else if ($user['admin'] != 0) {
        setcookie("admin", $user['name'], time() + (3600 * 12 * 30), "/"); // 1(имя куки) 2(у переменной $user берём имя, которое берётся с бд) 3(время жизни куки)
        header('location: /');
        session_destroy();
        exit();
    } else {
        setcookie("user", $user['name'], time() + (3600 * 12 * 30), "/"); // 1(имя куки) 2(у переменной $user берём имя, которое берётся с бд) 3(время жизни куки)
        header('location: /');
        session_destroy();
    };
```

Comment: Может быть проблема в том, что у Вас тело условия `if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || !isset($_COOKIE['admin']))` пустое? :)

Comment: а какие значения лежат в куках 'user' и 'admin'?

Comment: Увы добавляя тело условию, ничего не меняется. Как работало только при одном условии, так и работает (

Comment: То есть вы сейчас в вопросе написали не тот код, который пробовали, но просите нас найти в нем ошибку? В том коде, который мы не видим? Вам не кажется это несколько нелогичным?

Comment: @Ипатьев Не совсем понял ваше недовольство. Как я понял мне MyZik предположил, что у меня не работает условие из-за того, что в нём нету тела. Я добавил и проблема не ушла. Как была, так и осталась. В куках 'user' и 'admin' лежат выгруженные из бд имена владельцев аккаунтов. В последующем они используются для обращения к ним.

Comment: Это не недовольство, а удивление. код надо добавлять не в комментарий - там его прочитать невозможно, а в вопрос, нажав на кнопку "править"

Comment: Нет, ссылки на код не разрешаются. Надо вставить в вопрос сам код

Comment: ну и по поводу имён. То есть если я отправлю куку admin=Вася, то смогу добавлять и удалять товары, правильно?

Comment: @Ипатьев извиняюсь за код в комментарии впервые тут задаю вопрос. Раньше удавалось самим решать проблему, а в этот раз не могу найти решения. Я прикрепил ссылку на облако, там понятно написан код.

Comment: @Ипатьев Да, у куки ['admin'] появляется возможность добавлять товар на сайт, в будущем удалять и редактировать. У куки ['user'] доступ к корзине.

Comment: И как именно этот новый код "не работает"?

Comment: @Ипатьев if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || !isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) проблема именно в этой строчке(я так подозреваю), если использовать || !isset($_COOKIE['admin']), то он вообще не проверяет cookie, а если использовать только одно условие: 
( if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']): ) или ( if(!isset($_COOKIE['admin']): ), то всё работает, а вместе не хочет.

Comment: он проверяет. просто "он" проверяет обе. а учитывая что установлена всегда только одна из кук, то результат всегда false. чтобы это условие работало правильно, надо или поменять or на and, или,по закону ДеМоргана, убрать отрицания и поменять местами if и else, как это сделано в принятом ответе.

Comment: Но главная проблема здесь конечно в том, что любой вася с улицы сделает себя админом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простом коде проще разобраться. У опытных программистов есть несколько приёмов, позволяющих упростить код типа вашего. Во-первых надо дать осмысленные имена выражениям, которые проверяются в if'ах:

```php
<?php

$isUser = isset($_COOKIE['user']);
$isAdmin = isset($_COOKIE['admin']);

?>
```

Во-вторых лучше проверять позитивные условия (нашим мозгам так проще воспринимать утверждения):

```php
<?php if ($isUser || $isAdmin): ?>
    <?php if ($isAdmin): ?>
        кнопка "Добавить товар"
    <?php endif ?>
    кнопка "Выход"
<?php else: ?>
    кнопка "Логин"
<?php endif ?>
```

Как видите, так гораздо проще.

---

UPD: Обратите внимание, что кука -- просто HTTP-заголовок, который отправляет пользователь (любой пользователь может отправить "admin"). Если вам надо ограничить доступ к админскому функционалу, то следует использовать [сессии](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php).

Comment: Вооо! То что нужно, спасибо всем, кто пытался мне помочь, но этот способ оказался рабочим.

Comment: Егор, я понимаю что вопрос про булеву логику, но все-таки всегда стоит смотреть на шаг вперёд и заодно предупредить читателей  о принципальной уязвимости (или даже скорее полной бессмысленности) такой "защиты"

Answer (score 0):

Почему не написать так?

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['admin']) || isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) {
        //admin code
    } else {
        //user code
    }
} else {
    //login html
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ, но проблема таже. if (isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) { работает, а if (isset($_COOKIE['admin']) || isset($_COOKIE['user'])) { не работает, как бы пропуская его условие.